# Significato di "chiaitare"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> E fra un mese, fra un anno, Diamante potrà mandare un vaglia ai suoi genitori. Un vaglia vero. Angela la smetterà di lamentarsi. Di infelicitare tutti col suo rancore. Non si legherà piú ai piedi con una corda una suola di sughero. Se ne è sempre vergognato, perché le altre donne almeno un paio di paposce lo rimediavano e solo sua madre doveva camminare guardinga, come sui vetri, perché spesso la suola restava impigliata in una crosta di fango o di letame, e se lei strattonava con troppa forza si staccava. Quante volte l’aveva vista dibattersi per liberare il piede senza perdere la suola. Uno spettacolo penoso che gli faceva sanguinare il cuore. Angela la smetterà di **chiaitare**, di accusare Antonio perché è un incapace e un fallito.

Sapreste spiegare qual è il significato di "chiaitare"? Non ho trovato questo verbo su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino che sia un termine regionale, possibilmente derivato dal napoletano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il verbo **chiaitare**, o *chiaità*, come riportato in [questo vocabolario napoletano](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf) a pag.46 significa:

> **chiaità**: *intr.* discutere, dibattere, piatire.

L’accezione che più si adatta al contesto da te citato è [piatire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piatire/), cioè:

> **2.** Lamentarsi con tono querulo, fastidioso: *p. sulla propria miseria, sulla propria condizione;* anche assol.: *non fa che piatire*;